# How to implement a loop inside Piecewise?

Tags: piecewise

I wanna be able to use the Piecewise function such that I don't have to manually enter all the pieces. For example, say I define

```
f[x_]:={x,x^2,x^3}
```

Consider now

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{f[x][[1]],0<x<1},{f[x][[2]],1<x<2},{f[x][[3]],2<x<3}},{x,0,3}]
```

I want to be able to do this using some kind of loop inside Piecewise. How can I implement this

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps:

```
cond = # < x < # + 1 & /@ Range[0, 2];
f = {x, x^2, x^3};
Plot[Piecewise[Transpose[{f, cond}]], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]